# NSCocoaErrorDomain code=513 when write the documents folder

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, permissions

I had a program to write the bundle, it works in simulater but got error NSCocoaErrorDomain code=513 in devices.

After search, I founded that there is no permission to write the bundle, so I change the program. to write the documents folder

But after change it, I also found the same error NSCocoaErrorDomain code=513 when running in devices:

[image]

so what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

get the path of document directory

```
 - (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory 
     inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}
```

then save you file

```
NSString *path = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory].path 
                   stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"fileName.txt"];
[sampleText writeToFile:path atomically:YES
                   encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

Comment: so you think my documents path with problems ?

Comment: exactly there was a problem. but you can get path as NSString also.